# How to retreive all rows within of an excel file within in range of timestamp column from another excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I've been struggling with this python hw assignment for days and all I end up with is super messy code that doesnt work the way I need. So if you can help by giving me some directions or pseudo code that would be great.

I have two excel files. excel1 has a column of timestamps in the format yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS
and excel2 has multiple columns including a timestamp in the form of yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.f
I need to find all rows in excel2 with a timestamp that is equal to or within a 2 second range of one of the timestamps in excel 1 and then put that entire row(from excel2) into a new excel file.

Next, I need to find all rows in excel2 where column2=false and timestamp is NOT in excel1. And i need that in its own new excel file or as a second sheet on the first created excel file.

heres some visual

excel1

```
timestamp
2021-10-07 05:22:23
2021-10-07 07:25:54
2021-10-07 06:12:35
2021-10-07 05:23:58
```

excel2

```
timestamp                    isTrue      count
2021-10-07 05:22:23.4232     false       4
2021-10-07 07:25:53.2324     false       6
2021-10-07 01:13:34.2323     false       8
2021-10-07 02:24:58.2345     true        5
```

and my output would be:

```
newExcel Sheet One
timestamp                    isTrue      count
2021-10-07 05:22:23.4232     false       4
2021-10-07 07:25:53.2324     false       6
```

newExcel Sheet Two

```
2021-10-07 01:13:34.2323     false       8
```

Comment: I analyse your question.  You want to find the excel1 min time and subtract 2 secs from it.  let it be min1.  Find the max time and add 2 secs to it.  Let it be max1.  Then you sort excel2 time and filter off all those within this min1 and max1 and write to a file.  Then you do a second filter, all those in excel2 outside the min1 and max1 and is false ?  Correct ?

Comment: yes thats correct. how would i go about filtering?

Comment: I need a max and min for each timestamp in excel1 and then i have to find a timestamp in excel2 that is between max and min.

Comment: Please check my answer below.  If it answers the question as you have posted, kindly check the 'tick' mark to accept the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: You should include some of your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
t = df['timestamp'].to_numpy().reshape(len(df),1)
t
t1 = df1['timestamp'].to_numpy()
t1
min1 = t - pd.Timedelta(seconds=2)
max1 = t + pd.Timedelta(seconds=2)
min1
max1
```

Output:

```
array([['2021-10-07T05:22:23.000000000'],
       ['2021-10-07T07:25:54.000000000'],
       ['2021-10-07T06:12:35.000000000'],
       ['2021-10-07T05:23:58.000000000']], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
array(['2021-10-07T05:22:23.423200000', '2021-10-07T07:25:53.232400000',
       '2021-10-07T01:13:34.232300000', '2021-10-07T02:24:58.234500000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
array([['2021-10-07T05:22:21.000000000'],
       ['2021-10-07T07:25:52.000000000'],
       ['2021-10-07T06:12:33.000000000'],
       ['2021-10-07T05:23:56.000000000']], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
array([['2021-10-07T05:22:25.000000000'],
       ['2021-10-07T07:25:56.000000000'],
       ['2021-10-07T06:12:37.000000000'],
       ['2021-10-07T05:24:00.000000000']], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Code:

```
a = (t1 > min1)
a
b = (t1 < max1)
b
c = (a & b).any(axis=1)
c
```

Output:

```
array([[ True,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False]])
array([[ True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True]])
array([ True,  True, False, False])
```

Code:

```
df1[c.T]
df1[(~c.T) & (df1['isTrue']==False)]
```

Output:

[image]